# How to get the last words from a set of data in java?

Tags: java

I have a set of data, with multiple words and numbers...
How do I get the last word from the set of data?

Data Example:

1995    Jun 987 65  **Allison**

1995    Jul 973 85  **Erin**

1995    Aug 929 120 **Felix**

1995    Aug 968 95  **Humberto**

In the example, how do I get the bolded words (which is in the fourth column)?

```java
String year = scanner.nextLine().substring(0,4);
String month = scanner.nextLine().substring(5, 8);
String pressure = scanner.nextLine().substring(9, 12);
String windSpeed = scanner.nextLine().substring(13, 15);

System.out.println(scanner.nextLine().substring(scanner.nextLine().lastIndexOf(" " + 1))); //want the fourth column
```

Comment: do you have csv data?

Comment: This entirely depends on what format that data is in. If you're just looking at Strings, use a `substring()` on it to get the last word.

Comment: Could you please add an example of how the data is structured in your code? Without knowing the data structure, it's impossible to know how to do anything useful with it.

Comment: "Last word" is the key. use string split as array. Get last element from array result for the last word.

Comment: Edited, please check...

Comment: @glovemobile; it doesn't work, I get an error: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"

Comment: Can you explain what you think `scanner.nextLine()` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Input File content:

```
1995 Jun 987 65 Allison
1995 Jul 973 85 Erin
1995 Aug 929 120 Felix
1995 Aug 968 95 Humberto
```

Read File:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\tester.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] splited = line.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println("splited = " + splited[splited.length - 1]);
        }
        
    }
```

Output:

```
splited = Allison
splited = Erin
splited = Felix
splited = Humberto
```

Comment: It works for half of the data, the other half doesn't work....

Comment: what do you mean the other half? you said last word. every word must be separated by space, or specific delimiter, you specify it. otherwise, it's not word.

Comment: I have a data with about 168 of those lines; and I get like 15 of those in the output....
Also I should probably mention this (this could be the cause of the problem), I am reading the data from a file....

Comment: you mean there's data with multiple line?

Comment: if multiple lines you are referring is from example, you can use loop for reading every line.

Comment: yes, I am using scanner.nextLine() in a while loop....

Comment: @Overdrive I've update the answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is of type `String`, you can call the `split()` function on each data to separate the individual words in an array. Then you can simply access the 4th element of the resulting array.

Here is what I mean:

```
String dataElement = "1995 Jun 987 65 Allison";
String[] separateWords = dataElement.split(" ");
String result = separateWords[4];
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 1"